# Extrange logs appearing on /usr/share/nginx

Tags: nginx, logging, rsyslog

We have a remote syslog server where we store the logs of all our VMs.
Everything is working fine except that, on some machines with nginx, a log file with everything that has been sent to the remote syslog server has appeared on directory `/usr/share/nginx`.

I have checked the rsyslog conf aswell as the nginx conf but I cant't figure where is the problem. I delete that log file on `/usr/share/nginx` and after a few days it appears again.

```sh
django-03 mario:~$ ls -larth /usr/share/nginx/
total 1,5G
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root   23 dic  5  2018 html
drwxr-xr-x 150 root     root 4,0K abr 23 13:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root  148 sep  6 06:26 .
-rw-r--r--   1 www-data root 247M oct 17 09:31 syslog:server=someserver.vps:10514,tag=nginxerror
-rw-r--r--   1 www-data root 1,2G oct 17 09:33 syslog:server=someserver.vps:10514,tag=nginxaccess
```

Here is the rsyslog configuration.

```sh
###############
#### RULES ####
###############                 
... Rest of the file ...
.
.
.

*.* @@someserver.vps:10514
```

As you can see the rsyslog is sending everything to the someserver.vps:10514 and is working fine.

Here is the nginx configuration, we send logs both ways to the remote server and to the local machine on `/var/log/syslog`.

```sh
... Rest of the file ...
.
.
.
        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##
        log_format vhosts '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhosts;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log syslog:server=someserver.vps:10514,tag=nginxaccess vhosts;
        error_log syslog:server=someserver.vps:10514,tag=nginxerror;


        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

As you can see on `/usr/share/nginx/` is appearing the name of `someserver.vps` with all the logs. It's like 1.2G and we don't know why is appearing there.

Comment: What version of nginx are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Logging to syslog is available since version 1.7.1.

If your version is older, nginx would treat the syslog directives as a literal filename.

In that case this line:

```
access_log syslog:server=someserver.vps:10514,tag=nginxaccess vhosts;
```

configures nginx to write an access log to a file with the name `syslog:server=someserver.vps:10514,tag=nginxaccess`. There is no absolut path, so it is created in the daemons home directory.

Comment: But, its logging correctly to the remote syslog server someserver.vps:10514 creating a file nginxaccess with the access log. How can I prevent nginx to not write on /usr/share/nginx but still sending logs to remote server?
Thanks for your help

Comment: I was expecting your nginx to be to old and treating this as a filename instead. If the remote logging works, and no other logging directives are found in the configuration, I'd consider raising a bug report with nginx.

Comment: As a workaround you could replace the files with a symlink to /dev/null.

Comment: I'm using nginx/1.10.3, I'll check if there's any bug reports on this version. Thank you very much.

Comment: If it turns out to be a bug, please post it as an answer and accept it. Obviously my answer is wrong in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like nginx couldn't resolve the someserver.vps address (we had some dns problems a few days ago) and, as you said nginx was treating the syslog as a literal filename, and created on the daemons home directory.

We were receiving logs on the remote syslog server thanks to the rsyslog configuration. And that's what was confusing me.

Thank you very much for your help